How do I invert this function?
I have the following function that I want to invert to use in further calculations, i.e. I need to be able to plug in the expression $r = r(p)$ in further calculations where $r$ goes over the range given by CLOSEBOUND and FARBOUND. Note that $f(r)$ has a pole at some point, so I would also need to break this function up in two parts regardless.
f[r] =(2.23265 (-0.0225863 + 0.223203 r - 1.31861 r^2 + 1.60863 r^3 -0.413605 r^4 + 0.796262 r^5 - 4.97664 r^6 + 9.94907 (0.039306 - 0.109183 r + 1. r^2) Sqrt[(0.09 - 0.72 r + 1. r^2)^2 (0.408755 + 1.28 r + 1. r^2)]))/(0.168908 + 0.363791 r - 3.33192 r^2 + 1.92901 Sqrt[0.00988633 - 0.127223 r + 0.381269 r^2 + 0.524773 r^3 - 2.19782 r^4 - 0.477757 r^5 + 2.98598 r^6])^2
CLOSEBOUND = 0.725184775; FARBOUND = 1.787287549;
tempsol = Solve[p == f[r], r]
Solve doesn't produce a valid expression (even a Root would be fine). How do I proceed here?

Have you seen InverseFunction?

I tried working with this but didn't get any result. But maybe I'm doing something wrong here. Would you mind explaining a bit more?

Like this.

This doesn't really work, since f is not one-to-one.

Well, yes, because $f$ is not injective. Which part of the function do you want to invert?

As mentioned in the post, over the range specified by closebound and farbound for r. So naturally this needs to be broken up into two parts

Your function is not injective in the interval you provided. What do you mean by "broken up into two parts"? What should be the result of finv[20], for example?

I want an inverse for the first part up to the pole and then a second inverse from the pole up to the upper bound for r. There should be two functions such that evaluating them at e.g. 20 gives two different results

Determine the position of a singularity with FunctionSingularities, then use FindRoot to calculate the inverse functions.
{rMin, rMax} = {0.725, 1.787};
rSing = Quiet[Reduce[FunctionSingularities[f[r], r]]] // Last // Last
(* 1.22134 *)

fInv1[y_] := r /. FindRoot[f[r] - y, {r, 1, rMin, rSing}]
fInv2[y_] := r /. FindRoot[f[r] - y, {r, 1.5, rSing, rMax}]

{fInv1[20], fInv2[20]}
(* {1.09605, 1.34715} *)

Grid[{{Plot[f[r], {r, 0.72, 1.78}], Plot[{fInv1[y], fInv2[y]}, {y, 0.1, 20}]}}]



Wonderful! This is also easily adaptable to different functions, thanks!
